# Match only decimals that don't start with a $

Tags: regex

I have a text file that has many correct prices (decimals that start with a dollar sign). But there are a few that don't have a dollar sign. How can I find those?

In the following string, I only like to match. `72.00`

$40.00 `72.00` $6

I have tried negative lookbehind, like this `(?<!\$)\d+\.\d+` . But this one still matches part of the first decimal.

Comment: add a `\b` on it: `(?<!\$)\b\d+\.\d+\b` https://regex101.com/r/DZP8Gt/1

Comment: ...and if you use a /b you can get rid of the negative lookbehind,  because if /b is true then 'not $ preceding ' must be true too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the match with a word boundary to not trigger the lookbehind on every position when not matching a decimal value:

```
\b(?<!\$)\d+\.\d+\b
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/KVniVW/1).